# .net div trigger postback

Tags: .net

I would like to make a custom button, that will display 3 data bound labels and some other text. I would like this button to act fully like a asp:button control. Currently The only idea I have is to surround the labels with a div, trigger the divs click event to use a javascript event which causes a postback. I do not want this, **I would like to create a custom button that wires up the postback like a normal asp:button control does. Any ideas on how to do this would be great thank you very much.**

```
    <div class="someClass">
        <div>
          <asp:Label ID="lblONE" runat="server" Text='ONE'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTWO" runat="server" Text='TWO'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTHREE" runat='server' Text='THREE'></asp:Label>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I have applied css to the elements and want the button to end up looking like this. Except where it says bob steve mark you can sub in ONE TWO THREE respectively

Button Layout

[image: Button Layout]

Comment: what do you mean by data bound labels? do you get labels' text dynamically through db or any webservice?

Comment: Sorry, you're creating a custom button with labels? What do you mean wires up the postback?

Comment: @Waqas Raja  I mean the text is actually going to be <%# Eval('SOmething')%>

Comment: @Nicklamort     I would like to create a custom button that acts like a typcal .net button, with the exception that I want to be able to style 3 databound labels in it. I would like to be able to style anything in it and make it whatever I want, but the 3 labels are a baseline.

Comment: @waqas i have added what the styling for the control should look like.

Comment: LinkButton is there to accomplish it

Comment: I dont think a link button will accomplish what I need to do.

Comment: @gh9 have a look on the answer below; having sample code, if accomplished don't forget to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve custom layout by using LinkButton (as LinkButton implements IButtonControll by default)

```
<style type="text/css">
.button {
    border: solid thin black; text-decoration: none; display: block; height: 40px;
}
.one {
    color: green; text-transform: uppercase;
}
.two {
    color: red; text-transform: lowercase;
}
.three {
    color: blue; text-transform: capitalize;
}
</style>

    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="button">
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two">TWO</div>
    <div class="three">THREE</div>
    </asp:LinkButton>

// as you need DataBinding, so

    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="button">
    <div class="one"><%#Eval("ONE")%></div>
    <div class="two"><%#Eval("TWO")%></div>
    <div class="three"><%#Eval("THREE")%></div>
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I like the samples here. Essentially the same answer as mine but better. 8^D

Comment: @Dillie-O don't mind but I commented his question (suggesting him to use LinkButton) before start typing the sample code.

Comment: Great thanks, I have never used a linkbutton nor heard of it. Thank you very much raja!!

Comment: @gh9 if you like then here is more details about LinkButton http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y19

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LinkButton control and assign the text of each button through code. Similarly, you could also assign the CommandName and CommandArgument parameters to each LinkButton control as you render them, so they be processed uniquely if needs be.

If you want the entire text listed above to be a part of the LinkButton, you should be able to put all of the text and apply it to the Text property of the LinkButton. You just have to be careful on how your format your HTML.

From there you can process the click event of the button(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For what I think you're trying to accomplish, you're probably stuck with javascript. However, you can use javascript in your div container's onClick event to "wire" up the postback for your "button". `__doPostBack(document.getElementById('divID'), 'customArgument');`

You can then check if your div caused the post back in your code-behind like this (C#):

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "divID"){}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: there is no way to make this a custom server control or user control and implement the IButtoncontrol interface?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you should look into ajax. I'm not sure, but I think that would be your best bet